# Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '=' in *.php on line?

Tags: php

Every thing is **OK**.but i can not find **why** `Parse error`

`my code`

```
<?php
    if ($_REQUEST["submit"] == "ChangeTheBgColor")
        $bgcolor = strval($_REQUEST["thecolor"]);    
    else 
        $bgcolor = "white";
?>
<html>
<body bgcolor="<?php =$bgcolor; ?>" >
<form name= "color" method="get" action="<?php = $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];?>">
Enter a Color: 
<input type="text" name="thecolor" value="">
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="ChangeTheBgColor">
</form>
</body>

</html>
```

I use devPhp .
**Why I get the below Error and how Fix it?**

---

`Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '=' in C:\doc\demo.php on line 8`

---

Comment: `<?=$bgcolor; ?>` or `<?php echo $bgcolor; ?>`

Comment: surprise, surprise. You have error in line 8.

Comment: I know that in line 8 but i dont know why?Do you know?

Comment: you assign `$bgcolor` to what? IMHO nothing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should write :

```
<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];?>
```

And not :

```
<?php = $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];?>
```